# Dividing cell values in the column by column values in a different data table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the below table I am trying to find 'Number of Cases' as percentage of sum('Number of Cases') for each Make

```
              Make  | age | mileage   |  Test Result  | Number of Cases
0            ABARTH   0-3   <10,000           P                6
1            ABARTH   0-3   <50,000           P               23
2            ABARTH   0-3   <50,000           F                2
3            ABARTH   0-3   <50,000         PRS                1
4            ABARTH   0-3  <100,000           P                2
5            ABARTH   0-3  <100,000           F                1
6            ABARTH   3-5   <10,000           P                5
7            ABARTH   3-5   <50,000           P               77
```

Therefore I grouped the table as follows:

```
Make                    Number of Cases

ABARTH                         139
AC                              30
AC (ELECTRIC)                   33
ACCESS                           7
```

Tried using for loop and append the values I needed, but with no result as I am pretty sure I am using append function wrong:

```
rate = pd.Series()

for index, row in pass_rates.iterrows():
    rate.append(row['Number of Cases']/test_makes[test_makes['Make'] == row['Make']])
```

An return object is an empty series

So basically the result I am looking for should look something like this

```
              Make  | age | mileage   |  Test Result  |        %
0            ABARTH   0-3   <10,000           P              0.043
1            ABARTH   0-3   <50,000           P              0.165
2            ABARTH   0-3   <50,000           F              0.014
```

Answer (score 1):

To get your result, I'm just going to add a Total Cases column to your existing DataFrame based on the `groupby` results, and then just do division within the existing DataFrame.

```
total_cases = df.groupby('Make')['Number of Cases'].sum()
df['Total Cases'] = df['Make'].map(total_cases)
df['%'] = df['Number of Cases'] / df['Total Cases']
```

At this point you can drop the Total Cases column if you no longer wish to keep it.

Comment: Thanks, but I receive this error: TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable on line 2

Comment: Is your `total_cases` a Series or DataFrame? You can print the result of `type(total_cases)` to find out.  When I run the code it's a Series, which is callable by `map`, but your error indicates that your getting a DataFrame.  Are you doing anything different in the `groupby` that would cause it to return a DataFrame instead of a Series?